# Pandas multiply column with exception of Div/0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of the following:

```
 In: df['col1']
 Out[228]: 
 0      -0.1
 1      -0.2
 2      -0.1
 3     #DIV/0

 Name: col1, dtype: object
```

I would like to multiply all values by 100, set values as a float and round to 3 decimal places. I can do this using:
    df[col.name]=col.astype(float).round(places)*100
However, this code crashes due to the Div/0 value.

Can someone please help create a function that does the following rule but excludes all Div/0 or nan values:

```
 df[col.name]=col.astype(float).round(places)*100
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can replace non numeric values to missing values:

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce').round(places)*100
```